# Target CLASS NAME + specific data-id using Jquery

Tags: jquery, guid

I want to JQuery target the following item and change the TEXT using a dynamic GUID (ruID):

```
<span class="btn btn-mini emailIntive" data-id="a9c83938-0c2e-4433-a0f0-9aafc1aae541"> Invite </span>
```

The JQuery code I am using is:

```
$('.emailIntive' + data('id')=== ruID).text("SENT");
```

I am getting a 'data is not defined' error.

How can I target CLASS NAME + specific data-id using JQuery?

Comment: Do you have a function `data(...)` defined in your code? Probably not. You need to use jquery's .data() function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.something[data-id='+theUUID+']');
```

Which would evaluate to something like:

```
$('.something[data-id=a9c83938-0c2e-4433-a0f0-9aafc1aae541]');
```

Which will slect an element with the class `something` and the `data-id` value of `a9c83938-0c2e-4433-a0f0-9aafc1aae541`

Answer (score 4):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vchFR/)*

```
var ruID = $(".emailIntive").data('id');  //a9c83938-0c2e-4433-a0f0-9aafc1aae541
$('.emailIntive').data('id', ruID).text("SENT");
```

Or also:

```
var ruID = $(".emailIntive").data('id');  //a9c83938-0c2e-4433-a0f0-9aafc1aae541
$('.emailIntive[data-id='+ruID+']').text("SENT");
```